# Change MSB and leave remaining bits unchanged

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The question is as follows:

> Write a single line of C-code that sets the four MSB in DDRD to `1011` and leave the rest unchanged.

The best I can do is:

```
DDRD = (DDRD & 0xF) | (1<<7) | (1<<5) | (1<<4);
```

or just

```
DDRD = (DDRD & 0xF) | (0b1011 << 4);
```

It gets the job done, but it's certainly not the cleanest. Is there a better solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: Bit manipulation rarely goes any cleaner than this.

Comment: The *"Write a single line of C-code"* part of the assignment greatly reduces your options.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, touching DDR registers on the fly is bad practice. On many MCUs the change is not instant but may take several cycles, so if you change them on the fly you might cause data corruption. Well-designed programs set all DDR registers at one single place, very early on in the program.

Comment: @Lundin AVRs have a very simple, strongly ordered bus. BTW can you show an example of the not strongly ordered hardware register bus access? RMW will not cause any data corruption if register bits are RW.

Comment: @0___________ Freescale 68HC12/HCS12 and 68HC08/HCS08 (and maybe the 68HC11?) have some remark about waiting a few cycles between writing to DDR and performing port access. So you'd hurl in a few `asm NOP;` in between just to be safe.

Comment: @Lundin there is a significant difference between write after read and accessing the port after configuration change.

Comment: Please, don't use acronyms for the people that doesn't normally speaks english and doesn't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most readable and conventional form ought to be something like:

```
#define DDRD7 (1u << 7)
#define DDRD6 (1u << 6)
...
DDRD = (DDRD & 0x0Fu) | DDRD7 | DDRD5 | DDRD4;
```

Alternatively the bit masks could also be named something application-specific like `LED2` or whatever. Naming signals the same way in the firmware as in the schematic is very good practice.

"Magic numbers" should be avoided, except 0xF which is used for bit-masking purposes so it's fine to use and self-documenting. `DDRD & (DDRD0|DDRD1|DDRD2|DDRD3)` would be less readable.

`1<<` should always be avoided since left-shifting a signed integer (`1` has type `int`) is pretty much always a bug. Use `1u<<`.

Binary constants should be avoided since they are not (yet) standard and may not be supported. Plus they are very hard to read when numbers get large. Serious beginner programmers are expected to understand hex before writing their first line of code, so why more experienced programmers ever need to use binary, I don't know.

Regarding `0xFu` vs `0x0Fu`, they are identical, but the latter is self-documenting code for "I am aware that I'm dealing with an 8 bit register".

Comment: @0___________ What target? DDRD is a common register name present in a whole lot of Freescale/NXP parts as well as AVR microcontrollers. STM8 also uses similar naming.

Comment: I have not seen DDRx registers used this way (not something -> DDR) anywhere else. Any examples, please?

Comment: `1011` is just an arbitrary number by the assignment, it could be anything. And the assignment just *required* that you can only type it on a single line of C code, doesn't matter how much assembly code it generates (I guess).
My teacher just says my code is hard to read, so I'd like to be better at it in the future.

Comment: @Simon So maybe they meant that your magic numbers should be replaced by named constants. Because other than that, your code is not hard to read.